# Google Tasks API PHP: update tasks return 404 not found

Tags: php, google-api

Following the example at Google Reference (see below), the `update` return "404 not found". Here is the code as per Google Reference at now:

```
$task = $service->getTasks('@default', 'taskID');
$task->setStatus('completed');
$result = $service->updateTasks($task->getId(), '@default', $task);
echo $result->getCompleted();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved: at the moment I write, there is an error in [Google Reference](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/update). This is how I resolved in my code:

```
 $task = $service->tasks->get('@default', 'taskID');
 $task->setStatus('completed');
 $result = $service->tasks->update('@default', $task->getId(), $task);
```

Parameter `@default` has to be the first, and `taskId` has to be the second.